# My margin for bottom right items inside flexbox doesn't work

Tags: html, css, margin

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
  <title>Welcome to Meme facts website </title>
  <h1 style="text-align: center"> MEMES MENU </h1>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flex-box">
      <div class="topleft"></div>
      <div class="topright"></div>
      </div> <br> <br> <br>
    <div class="flex-box" style="background-color: white">
      <div class="bottomleft"</div>
      <div class="bottomright"</div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS :

```
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/yRF5c-O/blue-side-bubbles-4k-and-full-hd_4p0cs3stx__F0000.png")
}
.container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  background-color: #666666 ;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 555px;
}
.flex-box {
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #ADADAD;
  display: flex;
  flex-warp: wrap;
}
.topleft {
  flex: left;
  background-color: white;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
.topright {
  background-color: black;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
.bottomleft {
  background-color: red;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
.bottomright {
 background-color: blue;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
```

I tried with the other flexbox it worked fine, but with the 2nd one it doesn't work as the first box above, It seem like it being ignored, margin doesn't work either way.

it not moving to the right of the flexbox as it should on the upper flexbox, it stayed on the left and overlapping the other items.

Comment: you need to add your code in your question not a separate link

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML isn't correct, you forgot to close the div tag on line 17 & 18 after your class assignment!

```css
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/yRF5c-O/blue-side-bubbles-4k-and-full-hd_4p0cs3stx__F0000.png")
}
.container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  background-color: #666666 ;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 555px;
}
.flex-box {
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #ADADAD;
  display: flex;
  flex-warp: wrap;
}
.topleft {
  background-color: white;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
.topright {
  background-color: black;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
.bottomleft {
  background-color: red;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
.bottomright {
 background-color: blue;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
  <title>Welcome to Meme facts website </title>
  <h1 style="text-align: center"> MEMES MENU </h1>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flex-box">
      <div class="topleft"></div>
      <div class="topright"></div>
      </div> <br> <br> <br>
    <div class="flex-box" style="background-color: white">
      <div class="bottomleft"></div>
      <div class="bottomright"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```